# How i can list one rows with foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, foreach

I have one question for you.
Have this code right now:

```
 <?php
    use yii\helpers\Url; 
    use yii\helpers\Html;  
    use yii\web\JsExpression;

    ?>
    <form action="<?= Url::to(['/worker/equipment/updatecol']) ?>" id="editcol" method="POST">


    <div class="form-group">
    <?php foreach($columns as $column) { ?>
       <label >Edit title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?= $column->equipment_column_title ?>" name="equipment_column_title" placeholder="Put name.." />
    <?php } ?>  

        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <?php foreach($columns as $column) { ?>
        <label>Edit type</label>

        <select class="form-control" name="equipment_column_type">
      <option value="1" <?php if ($column->equipment_column_type==1) echo "selected='selected'"?>>Int</option>
      <option value="2" <?php if ($column->equipment_column_type==2) echo "selected='selected'"?>>Varchar</option>
      <option value="3" <?php if ($column->equipment_column_type==3) echo "selected='selected'"?>>Date</option>
      <option value="3" <?php if ($column->equipment_column_type==4) echo "selected='selected'"?>>File</option>
      </select>
        <?php } ?>   
      </div>


      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
       <?php foreach($columns as $column) { ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="column" value="<?= $column->equipment_column_id ?>" />
       <?php } ?>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update column</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my form for edit choosen column right?
Its yii2 framework and now my problem. This is form for editing my columns, but i dont want list all of fields, but one field i wanna edit. How i do it?

This function is my form controller:

```
public function actionUpdatecolumnform()

{

    $columns = EquipmentColumn :: find() -> all();
    return $this->renderAjax('_editcol',['columns'=>$columns]);

}
```

And this i have for updating columns:

```
public function actionUpdatecol(){
  $model = EquipmentColumn::findOne($_POST['id']);
  $model -> equipment_column_title = $_POST['equipment_column_title'];
  $model -> equipment_column_type = $_POST['equipment_column_type'];
  $model -> update();}
```

Now we going for jquery, where i have modal.

```
 $('.editcolumn').click(function() 
{   
    var essay_id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '".Url::to(['/worker/equipment/updatecolumnform'])."',
        data: 'id='+essay_id,
        success: function(data)

        {
            console.log(data);
            $('#update_col').modal('show');
            $('#edit_col').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#editcol').submit(function(){
        var th=$(this);
        console.log(th);

        $.ajax({
                        url: '".Url::to(['/worker/equipment/updatecol'])."',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: th.serialize(),
                        error: function(data,status,text) {alert(text);},
                        success: function(data) {

          var n=noty({
    text: '".Yii::t('app', 'Type was saved')."',
    type:'success',
    layout: 'topCenter',
    animation: {

        open: 'animated bounceInLeft', // Animate.css class names
        close: 'animated bounceOutLeft', // Animate.css class names
        easing: 'swing', // unavailable - no need
        speed: 500 // unavailable - no need
    }
    })
}
})
})
```

This two part of jquery scripts i using for submit edited fields.
My question is: This code list all of columns with titles and types, but i want list only one column with title and type which i want edit.
Thanks for the help :)
I think there is a problem with foreach, but im not sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

You update for given id but render all. With foreach you see all of records. If you want to see just the edited one data record, send one data to view.

```
$columns = EquipmentColumn::model()->findAllByPk($id);
```

With that code you get all the infos by given id which belongs to changed record.